# What is the rhetorical term used in the sentence "When he died, all he left us was alone"?

Tags: rhetorical-devices

From the lyrics to *Papa Was a Rollin’ Stone* by The Temptations:

> Papa was a rolling stone
> Wherever he laid his hat was his home
> And when he died **all he left us was alone**

What is the the name of this device?

Comment: It's sheer irony for "left nothing".

Comment: Does that include the play on the words "a loan"?

Comment: As @Cascabel points out, it might be a pun.

Comment: @Cascabel I don't think there is any deliberate pun here.

Comment: A deliberate garden path sentence played for surprise. Powerful.

Comment: @Centaurus The rhetorical device here (that I can't remember the name of) has to do with the expectation that the father left them an object of some sort (or at least a noun, I guess), rather than a turn of the phrase "to leave someone alone."

Comment: I now see it was already discussed https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15028/what-is-funny-in-this-paraprosdokian

Comment: "Left" is where the pun is. *leave someone something in your will* as opposed to *leave someone alone.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A **paraprosdokian** (/pærəprɒsˈdoʊkiən/) is a figure of speech in which
> the latter part of a sentence, phrase, or larger discourse is
> surprising or unexpected in a way that causes the reader or listener
> to reframe or reinterpret the first part. It is frequently used for
> humorous or dramatic effect, sometimes producing an anticlimax. For
> this reason, it is extremely popular among comedians and satirists
> such as Groucho Marx. ...
>
> Etymology "Paraprosdokian" comes from the Greek "παρά", meaning
> "against" and "προσδοκία", meaning "expectation".

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraprosdokian)

> **Paraprosdokian**
>
> Figure of speech in which the latter part of a sentence or phrase is
> surprising or unexpected; frequently used in a humorous situation.
>
> "**Where there's a will, I want to be in it,**" is a type of
> paraprosdokian.
>
> Etymology: From παρά + προσδοκία.

[definitions.net](https://www.definitions.net/definition/paraprosdokian)

**I’ve had a perfectly wonderful evening, but this wasn’t it.**
For the origin of this gem, see [quoteinvestigator.com](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2012/07/02/wonderful-party-not/)

**He taught me housekeeping; when I divorce I keep the house.**
"Zsa Zsa Gabor on her fifth husband, quoted by Ned Sherrin in Cutting Edge, 1984". [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/film/2016/dec/19/zsa-zsa-gabor-her-best-and-most-memorable-quotes)

Comment: Well, that was certainly unexpected. 

Comment: @GlobalCharm - You must be new to this site.

Comment: @GlobalCharm Did I do something verboten?

Comment: @DjinTonic. I was speaking in jest. The answer itself is first rate.

Comment: @GlobalCharm Thank you.