# What is it called when you build up a statement as something positive, and then make into something negative?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, irony

Is there a specific word for when the beginning of a statement is positive, and then you you turn it into a mockery or ridicule?

**Examples:**

"I really do love Rick, he is my favorite comedian, because he makes the rest of us appear funny."

"It's fun to be your new teacher. I said to the principal that I wanted the best class of the school, they weren't here, unfortunately."

"You know what the best thing about (City 1) is? It's just takes one hour to get back to (City 2)."

Obviously it's sarcastic, because it ridicules in a smart way, but is there another word to describe this specific type of sarcasm, when you build it up as if it was a compliment, and then the ending shows that it is not. It's not really irony because you say exactly what you mean. Maybe ambivalence?

Comment: If the second part  is a deliberate humorous turn or punchline, it could be the figure of speech known as  a *paraprosdokian*. See [What is the rhetorical term used in the sentence "When he died, all he left us was alone"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/571744/what-is-the-rhetorical-term-used-in-the-sentence-when-he-died-all-he-left-us-w/571746#571746)

Comment: @DjinTonic: That appears to be a duplicate of [Is there a name for this type of sentence structure: "She looks as though she's been poured into her clothes, and forgot to say 'when'"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/14949/2303). The answer there is also *paraprosdokian*.

Comment: @Robusto Yes -- no one had flagged the question as a duplicate and I answered it after seeing the comments there.